# "There was an error completing that action" when clicking 'Enable Crashlytics' on the console page

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm new to Android Studio and have a very base knowledge of programming; I'm just trying to troubleshoot my phone crashes. AFAIK I have set up everything correctly with Android Studio and when I click "Enable Crashlytics" on the console page I get error "There was an error completing that action" and I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help troubleshoot. But if the problem persists, you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the reply. I'll submit a ticket there but out of curiosity what additional information would prove useful? I don't seem to be given a lot to go off of, hence the vagueness.